# Revoke privleges for user on all schemas

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to revoke privleges for all schemas from a specific user and thought I could use a for loop for that. But I just can't get it to work.

I'm using dbeaver and a postgresql image in docker with version 11.3 to execute my commands. Here's what I tried so far:

```sql
FOR temprow IN
    SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata
LOOP
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on ALL tables in schema temprow.schema_name FROM TestUser1;
END LOOP;
```

I always get error near for loop as an exception. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: You can do that inside a `DO` statement, but you'd have to use dynamic SQL for the `REVOKE` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use psql and its `\gexec` functionality:

```sql
SELECT format('REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on ALL tables in schema %I FROM TestUser1', schema_name)
FROM information_schema.schemata;\gexec
```